Huge log backups due to enabling querystore
We have a SQL Server 2019 CU18 where we discovered a strange issue with querystore.
Normally the average size of the hourly logbackup is 40MB but as soon as we enable querystore the average size of the logbackup is 2.5GB.
There are (according to querystore) 140.000 queries executed/hour. This is about 40 executions/second.
This is the config of our querystore:
ALTER DATABASE [db_name]
SET QUERY_STORE = ON
    (
        OPERATION_MODE = READ_WRITE
        ,CLEANUP_POLICY = (STALE_QUERY_THRESHOLD_DAYS = 45)
        ,DATA_FLUSH_INTERVAL_SECONDS = 900
        ,MAX_STORAGE_SIZE_MB = 2048
        ,INTERVAL_LENGTH_MINUTES = 30
        ,SIZE_BASED_CLEANUP_MODE = AUTO
        ,QUERY_CAPTURE_MODE = AUTO
);

When I open such a big logbackup file with fn_dump_dblog I see that multiple transactions happen in the same second. The transactions all have the name 'SwapPage'.



Operation
CONTEXT
AllocUnitId
Page ID
Transaction Name




LOP_BEGIN_XACT
LCX_NULL
NULL
NULL
SwapPage


LOP_INSYSXACT
LCX_INDEX_INTERIOR
72057594047692800
0001:00056321
NULL


LOP_INSYSXACT
LCX_CLUSTERED
72057594047692800
0001:000a871c
NULL


LOP_INSYSXACT
LCX_CLUSTERED
72057594047692800
0001:0000041b
NULL


LOP_INSYSXACT
LCX_CLUSTERED
72057594047692800
0001:0000041c
NULL


LOP_FORMAT_PAGE
LCX_UNLINKED_REORG_PAGE
72057594047692800
0001:000a8715
NULL


LOP_MODIFY_HEADER
LCX_UNLINKED_REORG_PAGE
72057594047692800
0001:000a8715
NULL


LOP_INSYSXACT
LCX_CLUSTERED
72057594047692800
0001:000a8715
NULL


LOP_MODIFY_HEADER
LCX_HEAP
72057594047692800
0001:000a871c
NULL


LOP_MODIFY_HEADER
LCX_HEAP
72057594047692800
0001:0000041c
NULL


LOP_INSERT_ROWS
LCX_CLUSTERED
72057594047692800
0001:000a8715
NULL


LOP_MODIFY_HEADER
LCX_HEAP
72057594047692800
0001:000a8715
NULL


LOP_MODIFY_HEADER
LCX_HEAP
72057594047692800
0001:000a8715
NULL


LOP_MODIFY_ROW
LCX_INDEX_INTERIOR
72057594047692800
0001:00056321
NULL


LOP_MODIFY_HEADER
LCX_HEAP
72057594047692800
0001:0000041b
NULL


LOP_MODIFY_HEADER
LCX_HEAP
72057594047692800
0001:0000041b
NULL


LOP_MIGRATE_LOCKS
LCX_NULL
NULL
0001:000a8715
NULL


LOP_INSYSXACT
LCX_CLUSTERED
72057594047692800
0001:000a8715
NULL


LOP_INSYSXACT
LCX_CLUSTERED
72057594047692800
0001:0000041c
NULL


LOP_INSYSXACT
LCX_UNLINKED_REORG_PAGE
72057594047692800
0001:0000041b
NULL


LOP_INSYSXACT
LCX_CLUSTERED
72057594047692800
0001:000a871c
NULL


LOP_INSYSXACT
LCX_INDEX_INTERIOR
72057594047692800
0001:00056321
NULL


LOP_COMMIT_XACT
LCX_NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL



The allocation unit points to plan_persist_runtime_stats.
After a comment of Paul White I setup an Extended Event to capture query_store_index_rebuild_started and query_store_index_rebuild_finished. To my suprise querystore was doing index rebuilds.
This are the results of this trace:



event
timestamp
current_size_kb




query_store_index_rebuild_started
2024-12-05 07:51:10.353
874208


query_store_index_rebuild_finished
2024-12-05 07:52:29.073
868832


query_store_index_rebuild_started
2024-12-05 08:20:58.497
873504


query_store_index_rebuild_finished
2024-12-05 08:22:18.320
869152


query_store_index_rebuild_started
2024-12-05 08:36:03.147
874528


query_store_index_rebuild_finished
2024-12-05 08:37:19.670
869664


query_store_index_rebuild_started
2024-12-05 09:06:00.943
874336


query_store_index_rebuild_finished
2024-12-05 09:07:12.750
870304



It looks like the index rebuild is started around 874MB, the max size of querystore is set to 2048.
I also included the stacktrace of the query_store_index_rebuild_started event in the Extended Event.

sqllang!XeSqlPkg::CollectClientHostnameActionInvoke
sqllang!XeSqlPkg::CollectDatabaseIdActionInvoke
sqllang!XeSqlPkg::CollectDatabaseNameActionInvoke
sqllang!XeSqlPkg::CollectNtUsernameActionInvoke
sqllang!XeSqlPkg::CollectSessionIdActionInvoke
sqllang!XeSqlPkg::CollectTSqlStack<XE_ActionForwarder>
sqllang!XeSqlPkg::CollectTSqlStackActionInvoke
qds!XeQdsPkg::query_store_index_rebuild_started::Publish
qds!CDBQDS::ReclaimFreePages qds!CDBQDS::DoSizeRetention
qds!CDBQDS::ProcessQdsBackgroundTask
qds!CQDSManager::AcquireGenericQdsDbAndProcess<<lambda_e51628d7833f66b5a045fa5bf2d27953>>
qds!CDBQDS::ProcessQdsBackgroundTask
sqldk!SOS_Task::Param::Execute  sqldk!SOS_Scheduler::RunTask 
sqldk!SOS_Scheduler::ProcessTasks
sqldk!SchedulerManager::WorkerEntryPoint
sqldk!SystemThreadDispatcher::ProcessWorker
sqldk!SchedulerManager::ThreadEntryPoint  KERNEL32+0x17AC4
ntdll+0x5A8C1

I had hoped to find what is triggering the index rebuild but no such luck.
After some pointers of Zikato I added some extra querystore related events to my trace. This shows that the index rebuild only is triggered if a query_store_size_retention_cleanup_started event has occurred.
No rebuild:

Rebuild:


Everytime the cleanup runs 0KB has been deleted but apparently a rebuild is needed. What confuses me is the appearance of the cleanup event. I thought this would only be triggered when querystore reaches 90% of the max storage size.

Increasing the max size of the querystore doesn't make any difference.
Did anybody experienced the same issue or can somebody explain what is happening?
Other databases on the instance don't have this problem.

Inspection under a debugger reveals that Query Store runs index reorganize on its internal tables after any cleanup, whether triggered by size or age.

This makes some sense, since the purpose of cleanup is to free up space. Users cannot perform maintenance on the internal QDS tables. We also can't disable page locks, which would be one way to prevent reorganize running.
So, there's nothing you can do to disable this reorganizing behaviour in 2019; it's just what Query Store does. This explains the log growth.
SQL Server checks whether either size- or time-based cleanup is needed every time it persists Query Store data to disk. The 90% threshold for size-based cleanup is stored as a variable value rather than a hard-coded constant. This suggests the server may vary the percentage under some conditions.
Time-based cleanup can be prevented from firing with undocumented global trace flag 7748. There doesn't appear to be a similar facility for size-based cleanup.
SQL Server appears to always try time-based cleanup first (if enabled, and so long as the trace flag isn't set) regardless of the triggering condition. This may be because time-based cleanup involves much less overhead (no deciding which queries to evict based on relatively expensive queries run against the internal tables).
Curiously, SQL Server runs time-based cleanup every INTERVAL_LENGTH_MINUTES. Even if it doesn't find anything to do, the index reorganize is still performed afterwards.
There is an undocumented trace flag to prevent index reorganization, but it is only present in SQL Server 2022, not SQL Server 2019. Even if you were running SQL Server 2022, you'd need to contact Microsoft Support to get authorization to use the new flag.
Meanwhile, you could try disabling time-based cleanup with undocumented trace flag 7748 (or setting STALE_QUERY_THRESHOLD_DAYS to zero) for normal operations, allowing it to run during a period where you can tolerate the index reorganization.

Is 2GB enough to hold 45 days of Query Store data?
Ideally, you should avoid size-based cleanup as per this blog post from Kendra Little Query Store Size Based Cleanup Causes Performance Problems - How to Avoid It
Can you try to double the max storage size and see if the reindex frequency drops?
You can also monitor it with query_store_size_retention_cleanup_started XE and check if it correlates to the query_store_index_rebuild_started
